# Firebase Java Admin SDK 5.6.0 FirestoreClient constantly throws io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN

Tags: java, scala, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

When using the Firebase Admin SDK 5.6.0 for Java (in a Scala Play! application), we are constantly getting **io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN** anytime we get or set data using the **FirestoreClient**. The auth functions of Firebase seem to work without any issue, however.

Here is the exception we are getting:

```
ERROR application - method=GET uri=/v1/users/synchAllUsers remote-address=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 status=500 error=class java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
com.google.api.core.AbstractApiFuture.get(AbstractApiFuture.java:56)
services.FirebaseAdminService.createToken(FirebaseAdminService.scala:98)
services.UsersService.$anonfun$synchAllUsers$2(UsersService.scala:37)
scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:929)
scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:929)
scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1417)
scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:71)
scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:70)
scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
services.UsersService.$anonfun$synchAllUsers$1(UsersService.scala:34)
services.UsersService.$anonfun$synchAllUsers$1$adapted(UsersService.scala:34)
scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:251)
scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:209)
scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:287)
scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:29)
scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:29)
scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:81)
akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:38)
akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:43)
akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Here is the code we are running:

```
  private lazy val app = {
    FirebaseApp.getApps().stream().filter(a => a.getName == FirebaseApp.DEFAULT_APP_NAME).findFirst().orElseGet(
      () => {
        //val serviceAccount = new ByteArrayInputStream(Firebase.serviceAccountKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()))
        val serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("conf/gcp_service_account.json")

        val options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
          .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
          //.setDatabaseUrl("https://festive-bazaar-146119.firebaseio.com")
          .build()

        serviceAccount.close()

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options, FirebaseApp.DEFAULT_APP_NAME)
      }
    )
  }

  def createToken(user: User, claims: Map[String, Object] = Map()) = {

    val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(app)
    val db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore(app)

    val firebaseUser = getUserById(auth, user.id.toString)
    if (firebaseUser == null) {
      auth.createUserAsync(new CreateRequest()
        .setUid(user.id.toString)
        .setDisplayName(user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName)
        .setEmail(user.email)
        .setEmailVerified(true)
        .setDisabled(false)).get()
   }
    else {
      auth.updateUserAsync(new UpdateRequest(user.id.toString)
        .setDisplayName(user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName)
        .setEmail(user.email)
        .setEmailVerified(true)
        .setDisabled(false)).get()
    }
    // Set the user's info in our user metadata area
    val userInfoRec = new ImmutableMap.Builder[String, String]()
      .put("id", user.id.toString)
      .put("name", user.email)
      .put("email", user.email)
      .put("firstName", user.firstName)
      .put("lastName", user.lastName)
      .build()
db.collection("tenants").document(user.companyId.toString).collection("users").document(user.id.toString).get()
        val users = db.collection("tenants").get.get

        val result = db.collection("tenants").document(user.companyId.toString).collection("users").document(user.id.toString).set(userInfoRec)
    result.get() // **** This triggers the exception shown above, everytime ****

    auth.createCustomTokenAsync(user.id.toString, (claims + ("companyId" -> user.companyId.asInstanceOf[Object])).asJava).get()
  }
```

The comment above with the **** notes that is the line that triggers the exception. Has anyone else run into this problem or knows anything about this? In its current state, it makes the FirestoreClient completely useless to us as we can neither get or set data to the Firestore. I've checked the documentation, API reference, and generally Googled around but can't seem to find anything useful.

Comment: I tried the equivalent Java code, and it worked fine. Can you try enabling debug logs, and see if something useful shows up? Also is it only that one write query that fails, or are all interactions with Firestore throwing the same error (how about a simple read query, for example)?

Comment: Also are you using both Firestore and Cloud Datastore in the same Google Cloud project by any chance? This has been known to cause some issues.

Comment: We are using the auth functions and Firestore only. Not utilizing the Cloud Datastore at all.